# How to run install.py for MOSEK installation on Mac to use in MATLAB?

Tags: macos, matlab, mosek

I'm trying to install MOSEK on my Mac to use in MATLAB, but I could not get how to run the following step:

> Run the command:
>
> ```
> python <MSKHOME>/mosek/8/tools/platform/osx64x86/bin/install.py
> ```
>
> where `<MSKHOME>` is the directory where MOSEK was installed. This will set up the appropriate shared objects required when using MOSEK.

Where should I run this command on MATLAB or terminal or something else?
Another question what exactly `<MSKHOME>` should be?

Comment: As I understand from the manual, <MSKHOME> is where you unpacked MOSEK after downloading and run the command in terminal

Comment: Here is the link of instruction  https://docs.mosek.com/8.1/install/installation.html#general-setup >>do you think I need to have phyton on mac to be able to run this command?

Comment: Yes, definitely. `install.py` is a python script and requires python

Comment: Also is the following right to add path to matlab '/home/users/username/mosek' on mac to the following file location?

Comment: The manual says this: `<MSKHOME>/mosek/8/tools/platform/osx64x86/bin` (i.e. to the `bin` directory)

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, after installing phyton and running the command in phyton, I was not able to run in terminal btw.

Comment: Did you try running it in the terminal after installing python? or did you run it in the terminal before installing python only?